# How to print names of values in R

Tags: r, attributes, names

I read a SPSS file into R like this:

```
twobytwo <- read.spss("twobytwo.sav", use.value.labels=FALSE, to.data.frame=TRUE)
```

I used `use.value.labels=FALSE` because I don't want my variables to be turned into factors.

The data structure looks like this:

```
> str(twobytwo)
'data.frame':   2743 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ chm  : atomic  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named num  1 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "member" "none"
 $ cpv  : atomic  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named num  1 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "yes" "no"
 $ waves: atomic  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named num  1 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1998" "1970"
 - attr(*, "variable.labels")= Named chr  "church member" "conf party votes" ""
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "chm" "cpv" "waves"
 - attr(*, "codepage")= int 65001
```

As you can see, the variable `waves` is a 0-1 variable with names `1970` and `1998`.
However, I just can't find out how I can access these names. I'm writing a function in which I want to print these values (separately) as an output. So, based on the associated value(e.g. `1`), I want to print the name (for value `1`, this would be `1998`).

I hope my question is not to stupid, but I just can't seem to figure it out and I can't find a related thread.

Should I use attributes?

Comment: Have you tried `dimnames(twobytwo$waves)` (not tested)

Comment: Try `names(attr(twobytwo$waves,"value.labels"))[match(waves,attr(twobytwo$waves,"value.labels"))]`

Comment: Thanks nicola. Your code did not produce what I wanted, but using your code, I came to:

`names(attr(twobytwo$waves,"value.labels"))[match(levels(as.factor(twobytwo$waves))[1],attr(twobytwo$waves,"value.labels"))]` in which the number 1 is what I wanted to put in (the value).