# How do I extract and print the names of values in R?

Tags: r, attributes, names

I have data that looks on the surface as follows:
[image]

The data is structured as follows:

```
str(minstest)
List of 948
 $ : Named int [1:5] 4 6 11 16 75
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Mass " "Bite " "Burn " "Cyst " ...
 $ : Named int 37
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Impaired skin integrity "
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Abrasion "
 $ : Named int 33
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Infection of nail "
 $ : Named int 34
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Lesion "
```

What I want to do is replace the numbers in the V1 vector with the names.  Further, I would like to separate each name into distinct columns.

I tried multiple permutations of a recommendation that I found at:
[How to print names of values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127997/how-to-print-names-of-values-in-r)

Unfortunately, no option I have tried thus far has worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) Can you add output of `dput(minstest)`.

Comment: How about `lapply(minstest, names)`

Comment: I have unfortunately tried that before.  I get an error that the command implies a different number of rows.  I tried a variation on apply also.

Comment: Here is a snippet:      > dput(minstest)
structure(list(structure(c(4L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 75L), .Names = c("Mass ", 
"Bite ", "Burn ", "Cyst ", "Gout ")), structure(37L, .Names = "Impaired skin integrity "), 
    structure(2L, .Names = "Abrasion "), structure(33L, .Names = "Infection of nail "), 
    structure(34L, .Names = "Lesion "), structure(c(39L, 110L
    ), .Names = c("Creation of graft fistula for dialysis ", 
    "Skin care: graft site ")), structure(3L, .Names = "Blister "), 
    structure(c(3L, 4L, 21L, 23L), .Names = c("Blister ", "Mass ", 
    "Abscess ", "Mycosis ")),